# Keras loss functions how is the information passed

Tags: deep-learning, theano, keras, objective-function

I am fairly new to keras and DL and I am trying to build a loss function but I have questions about how the data from my network is passed through y_pred and y_true of the loss function.

As an example, my network has 3 different outputs here is one:

```
SEC5 = merge( [SEC1_up, SEC2_up, SEC3_up, SEC4_up], mode='concat', concat_axis=1 )

SEC5 = Convolution2D( 2,1,1, subsample=(1, 1), border_mode='same', activation="sigmoid" )( SEC5 )
```

SEC5 is now a 2 channel tensor that is predicting edges in one channel and non-edges in the other.

My model is created with the following line:

```
model = Model( input=inputs, output=[Final, ILLP2, SEC1, SEC2, SEC3, SEC4, SEC5] )
```

Where I perform binary cross entropy on Final, Squared loss on ILLP2, and then a custom loss for each of the SEC layers. When building the custom loss I have come across something that I don't understand. How are multiple channel layers (like SEC5) passed to the loss function? This is particularly important in my edge loss as I need to calculate the number of edges in the edge layer, and the number of non edges in the non edge layer.

What I don't understand is the actual variable in the loss function (y_true and y_pred) when I do this:

```
print 'y_true data'
print y_true.ndim
print y_true.type
print 'y_pred data'
print y_pred.ndim
print y_pred.type
```

I get the following values:

```
y_true data
2
TensorType(float32, matrix)
y_pred data
2
TensorType(float32, matrix)
```

And this is where i get really confused by everything. As I understand it, tensortypes of matrix can only be 2 dimensional, but I essentially have 3 dimensions? How does it deal with this information?

I feel like I should understand this before I go making elaborate loss functions of my own, any information you could provide  me with would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Michael

Comment: why your network output is 18 channel but you have only one channel y_true? isn't like you want to predict a grayscale image but your network output is a colorful image? you should give some information, it always depends on the case

Comment: From what I have read about theano as a backend the matrix class is only 2 dimensional, so my question is how can it in any case of multi channel inputs (like say an 18 channel convolution output) deal with that data? Or am i misunderstanding the theano documentation?

Comment: Could you post some code about your model? `18xNxM` can only be stored in rank 3 or more tensor. BTW I think most CNN use rank 4 tensors inside in either `NCWH` or `NWHC` format.

Comment: I have edited my question to include an example and a bit more information on what it is that I don't quite understand. Cheers